# Why when I run my phpunit test I get an empty response but the same route/user in Postman behaves as expected?

Tags: php, json, laravel, phpunit

While writing my tests for API the route api/users should return a list of users.
In Postman works as it should but in my phpunit test returns status 200 but an empty response hence assertJsonStructure() fails.

I have used the same user/password for Postman and for phpUnit.
I added dd() trying to debug the response and get an empty body.

The test

```
/** @test */                                                                                                                                                  
         public function testUserCanListUsers()                                                                                                                        
         {                                                                                                                                                             
         ┆   $user = factory(User::class)->make();                                                                                                                     
         ┆   \Auth::loginUsingId($user);                                                                                                                               
         ┆   $response = $this->actingAs($user)                                                                                                                        
         ┆   ┆   ->get('api/users')                                                                                                                                    
         ┆   ┆   ->assertStatus(200);                                                                                                                                  
         |   dd($response->getContent());                                                                                                                              
         ┆   $response->assertJsonStructure([                                                                                                                          
         ┆   ┆   "id",                                                                                                                                                 
         ┆   ┆   "name",                                                                                                                                               
         ┆   ┆   "email",                                                                                                                                              
         ┆   ┆   "email_verified_at",                                                                                                                                  
         ┆   ┆   "created_at",                                                                                                                                         
         ┆   ┆   "updated_at",                                                                                                                                         
         ┆   ]);                                                                                                                                                       
         }
```

The expected output which I get on Postman

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dr. Frederic Klein",
        "email": "vanessa.jacobi@example.org",
        "email_verified_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52",
        "created_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Prof. Alyce Considine",
        "email": "florence72@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52",
        "created_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Miss Jermaine Johns PhD",
        "email": "kenyon.stehr@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52",
        "created_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-31 20:03:52"
    },...
```

The output I get on phpUnit
When I dd($response);
"[]"

[image: Postman output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `factory()->make()` method does not save a record in the database. Therefore, when you make your api call in your test, you don't have any users, hence the empty response.

`factory()->create()` is used to actually save the record. So, just change your `factory()->make()` to `factory()->create()` and you should get a user in your response.

Comment: Thank you. You are right it was a silly mistake. `code` PHPUnit 7.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

"[{"id":1,"name":"Rhianna Terry","email":"abdullah40@example.com","email_verified_at":"2018-12-23 01:29:09","created_at":"2018-12-23 01:29:09","updated_at":"2018-12-23 01:29:09"}]"
`code` Which is the expected output for my dump. Now I can not get to validate the json but that is another business ;) .